# Can't save safe variables for further

Tags: variables

When I start Emacs it asks me if I want to allow "unsafe" variables which I agree and press '!' to save them for the future. Despite that, it still keeps asking me about it on every launch.

Here is the code that I like to run a per-directory basis:

```
     (defun jarfar/org-tasks-refile-targets-local ()
       "Set local 'org-refile-targets for specific org files with tasks."
       (setq-local org-refile-targets
         `(
            (,my/org-backlog-file-path :maxlevel . 1)
            (,my/org-inbox-file-path :maxlevel . 1)
            (,my/org-tasks-file-path :maxlevel . 1)
            (,my/org-taxes-file-path :maxlevel . 1)
            )))

     (dir-locals-set-class-variables 'jarfar/org-agenda-dir-class
       '((nil . (
          (eval . (progn (jarfar/org-tasks-refile-targets-local)))
          ))))

     (dir-locals-set-directory-class org-agenda-directory 'jarfar/org-agenda-dir-class)
```

I tried many ways of suppressing this confirmation window but it keeps popping up.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this with:

```
(setq enable-local-eval t)
(setq safe-local-eval-forms (list))
(add-to-list 'safe-local-eval-forms '(progn (jarfar/org-tasks-refile-targets-local)))
```

This post was helpful https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/58332/18445.